# Boolean multireturn refactoring

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

What do you think will be the best way to refactor this kind of boolean method?

```
if (someService.isTrue(importantArg)) {
    return true;
} else if (someService.isSomeTrue(anotherArg)) {
    return isAnotherCondition(entry);
} else {
    return super.thisMethod();
}
```

Comment: Why does it need refactoring?

Comment: Do you think this multireturn mess is acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

This is a minor refactoring, but you can remove the elses as you can't reach that code if the previous condition was true (if it was true, it would have returned a value and exited the method)

```
if (someService.isTrue(importantArg)) {
    return true;
} 

if (someService.isSomeTrue(anotherArg)) {
    return isAnotherCondition(entry);
}

return super.thisMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return someService.isTrue(importantArg) || (someService.isSomeTrue(anotherArg)  
       && isAnotherCondition(entry)) || super.thisMethod();
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider No, but op didn't ask for anything more readable. he wanted it refactored. So i pretended the shortest possible solution

Comment: I have never heard of refactoring to make code _less_ readable. So I would suggest that this does not answer the question.

Comment: How can you be sure that `super.thisMethod()` returns a `boolean`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger it's obvious, what else can it return? The method returns `true` in the first case...

Comment: @ChetanKinger the method returns `boolean` values, so `super.thisMethod()` must aswell.

Comment: @BoristheSpider My bad. I half read the question assuming the value was being assigned to a boolean rather than returning a boolean.